# Espresso - Unable to perform the button click using espresso

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I'm currently new to automation testing and performing automation tests with Espresso using Android Studio, I'm trying to perform automation testing for the login screen, I'm currently having trouble performing the click for a specific button.
I have tried multiple ways button nothing works for me. I am referring the following document to implement and below is my sample code and crash report.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class LoginTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);
    @Test
    public void OnLoginButtonClick() throws InterruptedException {
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.edtUserName)).perform(ViewActions.typeText("xxxxx"));
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.edtPassword)).perform(ViewActions.typeText("xxxxxxx"));
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.btnLogin)).perform(ViewActions.scrollTo(),ViewActions.click());
    }
}
```

### Crash Report:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll to' on view 'Animations or transitions are enabled on the target device.

with id: xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx:id/btnLogin'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:80)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at com.msf.opx.LoginTest.OnLoginButtonClick(LoginTest.java:50)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1873)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
(view has effective visibility=VISIBLE and is descendant of a: (is assignable from class: class android.widget.ScrollView or is assignable from class: class android.widget.HorizontalScrollView))
Target view: "Button{id=2131165273, res-name=btnLogin, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1320, height=152, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=60.0, y=1387.0, text=Login, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
at
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Animations or transitions are enabled on the target device.

Espresso doesn't work well with animations due to the visual state delays they introduce. You need to disable animations on your device. Firstly, [enable developer options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options.html)

Open the Settings app.

1. Scroll to the bottom and select About phone.
2. Scroll to the bottom and tap Build number 7 times.
3. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options near the bottom.
4. Access Developer Options from Settings app, and under the Drawing section, switch all of the following options to Animation Off:

   1. Window animation scale
   2. Transition animation scale
   3. Animator duration scale

Comment: A newer version of espresso points to that link (in a logcat message) which also explains how to disable those settings: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup#set-up-environment

Comment: In my case all of 3 options are off still there errors are coming .. any solutions for that how can we remove it?